# Lock/freeze nav bar/ whole html page till other html page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building currently my own web application. In the header of this application there is a navigation bar.

I added the same navigation bar to all my html pages, so that it stays seen when navigating between pages and set the nav-element to active to which page I am on now.

My problem is this nav-bar shows every time that it is loading when I am navigating from one page to another.(When i click on a link in it!)

So now I thought if it would be a trick that when I click on a link on my current page, that the current page should be locked/ friezed till the another page has loaded and continue working. And do not see on the page the loading process.

Here's [a JS Example](https://jsfiddle.net/a05jcr0s/1/)!

```
<div class="scrollmenu" id="myHeader">
    <a style="float:left" href="index.html">Menu</a>
    <a style="float:left" href="page1.html">Page1</a>
    <a style="float:left" href="page2.html">Page2</a>
    <a style="float:right" href="#Search">Search</a>    
</div>
```

Is such possible in Javascript? Something like VBA screen updating.

I am thankful for every tip or solution!
Cheers!

Comment: A neat question in my opinion.Trying to think out loud... As soon as you click a link or a button, your request is sent, which means that DOM is cleared and waiting for the next response. That blank page you are seeing is the waiting process. I am not saying that it can't be done. Eg: You can get your pages with Ajax but does is worth it.

Yet, I am curious if someone can figure out a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my goal is to add more elements to the nav bar, and this is not possible with AJAX, i tested it already :(

Comment: @Basch you have no idea what your talking about. Go learn how to use web API's correctly.

Comment: Therefore i asked if such a process is possible :)

Comment: You can use Ajax to achieve this. I don't know why you're claiming _"this is not possible with AJAX"_. If you've attempted it already, and it didn't work, [edit] your question to include a [mcve] so others can help fix it.

Comment: @KirkBeard I am building a web application of an object network, for studying issues, do you mean I ask again in a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior that you're describing is accomplished via single page application (SPA) architecture. With traditionally linked documents, where you're requesting pages from a server, delaying the loading of the requested resource--for the sake of visual continuity--will give the impression of a slower than normal connection. This would more than likely frustrate your users.

Comment: The loading time is approximately 540 ms, but what you are saying is true and makes sense. Thank you!